# Android Text Scaling on different resolutions same density

Tags: android, size, resolution

I have 2 devices, a 1024x600 7" tablet hdpi running Gingerbread and a hub attached to a touchscreen which is 1920x1008 22" in size, hdpi running ICS. The Android OS seems to consider both as "large" (240dp).

So, they have the same actual density (240dpi), same generalized density (hdpi), same generalized size (large) but different actual size (7" vs 22")

The text and spacing dimensions that I specify for my layout work great on the 22", but then on the 7" they look enormous and dont fit on the screen.

I've tried using dp and sp, no difference as I think the problem is that Android sees these things as the same size / density. Does anyone have any recommendations on how I can be able to scale sizes appropriately?
This program wil also eventually need to be supported on a 4.5" handheld as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, my previous answer was completely wrong = )

Ideally, you should be able to design for the 7" tablet and have your layout scale up to the TV.  But if that doesn't work you should be able to use something like layout-sw1008dp.  The "sw" prefix allows you to specify the minimum dimension of the smallest side of the screen - so in the case of a TV, the height.

Comment: Yes I think this is what is tripping me up - the bigger one is not actually a device with a built in screen but a box with an HDMI output to screens that range from 22" up to 42". But again, Android only sees it as a "large" device. Not sure how to address this...

Comment: I added resource folders for values-1920x1008 and values-1024x600 - now I am able to modify the values in each and have them used on the appropriate devices. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing such problem in my application. But i found a good solution for this.
I have only one layout for `tablet` and directory name is `layout-sw600dp`.
Now, when part came to height and width problems, I have created several different `values` directory in which i place `dimensions` and `font size` and other stubs. So there will be no `constant` value in `layout` of tablet screen.

```
androd:layout_width:"60dp" // i drop this scenario

androd:layout_width:"@dimen/tab_width" // i used this scenario
```

and your `values` directory name will be like

```
values-xlarge
values-large
```

All the values will be fetched from your values directory. It will not create different layout, but one layout can be used multiple times.

See my [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108074/layouts-on-different-models-of-mobiles/14108211#14108211) which may help you.