# Screen Compatibility issue in android

Tags: android, layout, tabs, imagebutton

I have a problem regarding my app.I have created tab bar using image button,when I run the app in 480*800 hdpi device the tab bar images are displaying perfectly when I run in 240*320 device the images in image button are not displaying properly.I have created the drawable folders and added the images also

```
drawable
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
```

Comment: an you provide which type of layout structure you have created?

Comment: @ChintanRathod layout structure means

Comment: in resources directory, as you have created/maintain `drawable` pattern, as this layout also there. tell me those.

Comment: i have used layout,layout-small,layout-large..but it does not make any changes

Comment: i think you have to put different size images as per it compatible with screen. what you have did?

Comment: @Sumedh No,i put same images in drawable,drawable-hpdi,..in every folder

Comment: no you have to put different size images..based on screen resolution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following scenario of layout. I found at http://jamil.fluidsoul.net/2011/03/06/creating-android-applications-for-multiple-screen-sizes.

```
Low density Small screens QVGA 240x320 (120dpi):

layout-small-ldpi (240x320)  
layout-small-land-ldpi (320x240)

Low density Normal screens WVGA400 240x400 (x432) (120dpi):

layout-ldpi  (240 x 400 )
layout-land-ldpi  (400 x 240 )

Medium density Normal screens HVGA 320x480 (160dpi):

layout-mdpi (320 x 480 )
layout-land-mdpi (480 x 320 )

Medium density Large screens HVGA 320x480 (160dpi):

layout-large-mdpi (320 x 480 )
layout-large-land-mdpi (480 x 320)

Galaxy Tab ( 240 dpi ):

layout-large  (600 x 1024) 
layout-large-land  (1024 x 600)

High density Normal screens WVGA800 480x800 (x854) (240 dpi):

layout-hdpi (480 x 800)
layout-land-hdpi (800 x 480)

Xoom (medium density large but 1280x800 res) (160 dpi):

layout-xlarge (800 x 1280)
layout-xlarge-land (1280 x 800)
```

If outcome display in Graphical layout best matches with all other, you will get same output in original device also.

Comment: you should. If view display is different what you want. Otherwise there is also other way you can find at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108074/layouts-on-different-models-of-mobiles/14108211#14108211

Comment: i have created layout,layout-normal,layout-large..but still its not working,i have to put the same layout for every screen right

Comment: as per your question, you should have 2 layout like layout-small and layout. Two are sufficient to do all work. If not working, something goes wrong in your code because I use this scenario in my application and it works fine for me.

Comment: i have one doubt that i can use the same layout for each and every layout folder..

Comment: depends. If its normal screen, you can. But I faced problem in large and xlarge screen due to more resolutions and screen sized then normal and small screen.

Comment: @ranjith thanks for update.. Might be domain is no more exist. Answer was posted 2 years back.. :(

Answer (score 1):

For detail, please refer to [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

To summarize, you must declare each supporting screen sizes in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. For example, you have to include the following:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

To support 240*320, you must do the following:

1: In `AndroidManifest.xml`, include

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" />
```

2: Create different `layout-small` folder:

```
res/layout/layout-small/
```

3: Create `drawable-ldpi` folder (you already did):

```
res/drawable-ldpi/
```

Comment: though i have used the layout,layout small it does not make any change

Answer (score 0):

You have to read below document first:-
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

or

[Is there a list of screen resolutions for all Android based phones and tablets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587854/is-there-a-list-of-screen-resolutions-for-all-android-based-phones-and-tablets)

above also hope use full to you.

Comment: though i have used the layout,layout small it doesnot make any change