# how to support all the devices under mdpi folder

Tags: android, device, android-screen-support, mdpi

Im very much confused on how will I be able to support all the different android devices that falls under the **mdpi** category where in fact they all have different screen sizes...

I was able to support the HVGA slider (320x480) but it looks awful when I tried it on other devices.

Can anyone explain to me in the simplest way possible on how I can support them all....

Thanks

Comment: read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354949/screen-compatability-issue-in-android/15355166#15355166

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this doc [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

And for layout and drawables you can define this way

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I already did what you mentioned above but still all my <b>mdpi</b> devices looks different from each other. I was specifically talking about the 5.1" WVGA (480x800 mdpi) and 3.2" QVGA (ADP2) (320x480 mdpi). With regards to the link you gave, Ive already seen that but I find it hard to understand. thanks again...

Answer (score -1):

you can add all your images under drawable folder only so it will support on all type of devices.
In Android it different size of drawable is created to support on different size of devices.But if you need to support on all devices just put your images under "drawable" folder.

Comment: thanks for your response, I'll definitely try your recommendation and will get back to you on how things goes...