# Unit for Layout on tablet and smartphone

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to develop an app for smartphones and tablets. Now my problem is that my layout isn't scalled in the right dimensens. On a 10' tablet it looks like this:

[image: 10' tablet]

But this here are screenshoots from a 7' tablet and from a smartphone:

### [image: 7' tablet]

[image: smartphone]

I would like to set a min width and height for the ImageView and scale it up and down depending on the screen size so in each layout the ListView is visible. Which unit do I have to use for the ImageView width and height? I tried with dp, in and some more but that does not help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/imageViewWidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/imageVewHeight"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```

**scaleType="fitXY"** will scale your image and fit with *ImageView* width and height. This will solve your problem.

**Edit**

In your **values** directory, open **strings.xml** file, then add following lines

```
<dimen name="imageViewWidth">30dp</dimen>
<dimen name="imageViewHeight">30dp</dimen>
```

Now, open **values-sw600dp** directory (of not, create one) and open **strings.xml** file (if not, copy from other *values* directory).

```
<dimen name="imageViewWidth">100dp</dimen>
<dimen name="imageViewHeight">100dp</dimen>
```

Now, open **values-sw720dp** directory (of not, create one) and open **strings.xml** file (if not, copy from other *values* directory).

```
<dimen name="imageViewWidth">120dp</dimen>
<dimen name="imageViewHeight">120dp</dimen>
```

This will solve your problem of different sizes of ImageView for different layouts.

Still can't understand, read my answer at

- [Android Universal App Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668271/android-universal-app-approach/16669294#16669294)
- [Layouts on different models of mobiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108074/layouts-on-different-models-of-mobiles/14108211#14108211)

Comment: okay thank you it's better now but I think not perfect. It's okay on a 7' tablet but on the smartphone it is still to big. I don't know how dp is calculated but I think there must be a factor to set the width and height. Can I edit this factor?